# Owner Draw ListView "smearing" when scrolling

Tags: c#, graphics, listview, ownerdrawn

I have an ownerdrawn ListView that "smears" when I scroll. It only affects the last displayed item as it moves into the visible are of the list...

It looks like:

> Blah
>   Blah
>   Blah

...have all been drawn on top of each other 1 pixel apart.
The code in the DrawItem event is of the form

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + mIconSize.Width, 
   e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
e.Graphics.DrawString(episode.ToString(), this.Font, mBlackBrush, rect);
```

I'm completely stumped. 
Any ideas gratefully appreciated!
Dave

Comment: It's not a duble buffering issue (I tried that) thanks for the ideas though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable double buffering for ListView by deriving from it and setting `DoubleBuffered = true`.  There's a noticeable reduction in flicker, especially in Tile view, once you turn Double Buffering on.

Comment: Turns out it was a double buffering problem. I needed to create a class inheriting from ListView and turn double buffering on in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

In detail view drawing do all of your drawing in DrawSubItem(...).  The problem is drawItem is getting called for the first item and DrawSubitem is also for the same item ... with slightly different bounds.

Comment: That sounds sensible I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

also, int the form's own properties, you can enable DoubleBuffer.
additionally, there are a couple of commands you can use.

More information can be found by searching DoubleBuffer C# at google (sorry, as a new user I can't post links).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the ListView control.